# Remove element from ArrayList using ListIterator in loop inside loop

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, iterator, listiterator

My requirement is to remove from ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<User> user = new ArrayList<User>();

ListIterator<User> outerIterator = null;
ListIterator<User> innerIterator = null;

User outer = null;
User inner = null;

for(outerIterator = user.listIterator(); outerIterator.hasNext();) {
    outer = outerIterator.next();
    for(innerIterator = user.listIterator(); innerIterator.hasNext();) {
        inner = innerIterator.next();
        if(SomeOperationOn(outer,inner)) {
            innerIterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Above code is giving exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

as expected, because I am trying to remove from innerIterator while outerIterator is Iterator on same object(user).

Is there any way to remove element from ArrayList using ListIterator in loop inside loop?

Comment: Even if you resolve the `ConcurrentModificationException`, because of the call to `outerIterator.remove()`, your `ArrayList` will be empty at the end of this code.  Is this what you want?

Comment: outerIterator.remove() I used just to check, but yes at the end of looping list will be empty.

Comment: Then why not simply declare a new empty list of equal size? (or reinitialize this one?)

Comment: Then `user.clear()` will clear it for you and the iterators are unnecessary.

Comment: Something that you can do is use another list to maintain the list of elements to be removed and remove them at the end.

Comment: its actually a part of a multi threaded application, there is more code inside if(). for now just ignore outerIterator.remove();

Comment: Then please edit your question to remove that line; it changes the entire purpose of the code.

Answer (score 1):

In isolation, calling `remove()` on an `Iterator` is the proper way to avoid a `ConcurrentModificationException` when removing an item from a collection you're iterating.  However, you have *two* `Iterator`s iterating over the same `ArrayList`.  When you call `remove()` on `innerIterator`, `outerIterator` notices that the list has changed, and it throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

In this case, if `SomeOperationOn` indicates that the item needs to be removed, then instead of removing it right away, store `inner` in a temporary `List` of items to be removed later.  After the `for` loop on the iterators completes, call `removeAll` passing this temporary list.